# Direct sum of subspaces, elements = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

For $ V = A_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus ... \oplus A_k $ , where $ A_1, A_2,...,A_k$ are subspaces of $ V $.

Explain why for $ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = 0 $ with each element $a_i \ \epsilon \ A_i $ we can deduce each $a_i = 0 $.

I am assuming that you can start with the statement,

$ A_1 \bigcap A_2 \bigcap ... \bigcap A_k = \{0\}$

but don't know how to take this from here.

Comment: The rest of the proof is very similar to the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case.  What would you do with real valued vectors?

Comment: you need a stronger assumption (which is implied by the $\oplus$: $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$

Comment: @Simon: Your stronger assumption is still not enough.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: true. I feel stupid now. Anyway, the answers below are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume $A_i \cap \oplus_{j\neq i} A_j =\{0\}$ (or more precisely  $A_i \cap \Sigma_{j\neq i} A_j =\{0\}$) for any $i$ which is in fact equivalent to the statement afterwards.

Comment: @egreg Thanks you are right! Need a stronger assumption

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define for a set of subspaces to give a direct sum.

I usually define $A_1,\dots,A_k$ to be independent subspaces of $V$ if (and only if) from $a_i\in A_i$ and $a_1+\dots+a_k$, it follows that $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_k=0$.

In this case we can write $A_1+\dots+A_k=A_1\oplus\dots\oplus A_k$.

An equivalent statement is that, for $i=1,2,\dots,k$,
$$
A_i\cap \biggl(\, \sum_{\substack{1\le j\le k\\j\ne i}}A_j\biggr)=\{0\}
$$
It is not sufficient to assume $A_i\cap A_j=\{0\}$, for $i\ne j$, nor $A_1\cap A_2\cap\dots\cap A_k=\{0\}$ (which is weaker).

For instance, if $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and we set $A_1=\langle e_1\rangle$, $A_2=\langle e_2\rangle$, $A_3=\langle e_1+e_2\rangle$, we have $A_i\cap A_j=\{0\}$ for $i\ne j$, but the three subspaces aren't independent, since $e_1+e_2-(e_1+e_2)=0$.

For finite dimensional spaces, independence is equivalent to
$$
\dim(A_1+\dots+A_k)=\sum_{1\le i\le k}\dim A_i
$$